# c# Google Chrome crashes with a call from the process.start function

Tags: c#, google-chrome, crash

I have several Windows users on Windows Server 2022. the program starts my default browser with the process.start function. If I set chrome as the default browser, its only starts up on one user,but crashes on others? Can you help?

In case Internet Explorer is the default browser, it works in any case...
I reinstalled chrome and made sure that the settings were the same for all users

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We currently have *no idea* what your code looks like.

Comment: (And please don't create duplicate questions. Instead, edit your existing question to provide more information - including an [mcve].)